# C++ execution time test

Tags: c++, performance, loops, testing

Im testing this code:

```
string teststring = "";
int i = 0;

while ( i < 100000000 ) {

i++;

}
```

The execution time is: 0.359 s.

Then I try to do the exact same test again, but this time Ive added one extra line within the loop:

```
string teststring = "";
int i = 0;

while ( i < 100000000 ) {

i++;
teststring += "something random";


}
```

The execution time is 4 s.

Its one extra line, should it really take that much longer? Can I do something different to improve this?

Comment: `int i = 0; while ( i < 100000000 ) {i++;}` likely gets optimized to `int i = 100000000;` or something similar.

Comment: Beware that appending text to a string is a significantly more involved process than incrementing an integer.

Comment: You can play around with [goldbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/wMr9DR) to see what exactly the compiler produces. Don't forget optimization flags, as profiling unoptimized code is almost never relevant.

Comment: It likely gets optimised away altogether. I have a short blog article on this at https://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/the-joy-of-benchmarks/

Comment: Which one do you think takes more time? Incrementing a variable 100 million times or creating a 1.6-gigabyte string? # of lines != execution time. Incrementing an int is done directly by your processor with a few instructions while appending to a string is a lot more complicated. For starters, all 16 characters need to be copied.

Comment: (1) compile with optimisations on and list the relevant compilation options in the question. (2) `std::string::reserve(a big number)` outside the loop.

Comment: "Its one extra line, should it really take that much longer?" I can easily write one line of code that will make your program slower in infinite times. What is the point?

Comment: [Evil overlord rule 46](http://www.eviloverlord.com/lists/overlord.html): *If an advisor says to me "My liege, he is but one man. What can one man possibly do?", I will reply "This." and kill the advisor.*

Comment: Search the internet for "How to benchmark c++ programs" for information on benchmarking (measuring performance of) C++ programs.  There is a lot to take into consideration before comparing with other languages, executables or platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would `teststring += "something random";` be implemented? Something like:

```
str = "something random";
for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++ )
    teststring[teststring.length+i] = str[i];
```

Not to mention if `teststring` isn't big enough, it has to make a new region of memory twice as large, and copy every single byte over, and then continue (teststring will grow very large in your code, making that copy operation quite expensive). This is very complicated in comparison to `i++`, so it makes sense that the latter is much faster.

Comment: So the string size should be predefined and as precise as possible, if I have understood you correctly

Comment: @QrazyNeo I'm not sure what you mean. predefined and as precise as possible?

Comment: Oh, if you mean to avoid teststring having to make a new region of memory, yes absolutely. Better to make it a bit bigger too since the copy operation is expensive and a bigger string is no big deal. `string::reserve` will help. Even if you do this though, the inner for loop iterates 16 times, so it should theoretically still be much longer than the `i++` alone, even if the CPU tries to run as much as it can in parallel (Doing all the `teststring[end+i]` writes at the same time since they're independent).

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a little. Will also take a closer look at optimization as others here have suggested

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nicholas Pipitone's point, an optimizing compiler can legitimately eliminate the original for loop and replace it with:

int i=100000001;

The optimizing compiler could do the same for the string concatentation, but it probably didn't bother catching that case (possibly because the string concatentation function may indicate it can throw exceptions, which the compiler may not know how to deal with).